# Selector not finding nodes for `dbt test`

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to define a dbt [YAML selector](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/yaml-selectors) so that I can run schema tests for a particular set of models.

The YAML selector looks sort of like this:

```
selectors:
  - name: test_selector
    definition:
      union:
        - intersection:
            - node+
            - tag:tag1
        - intersection:
            - node+
            - tag:tag2
        - intersection:
            - node+
            - +tag:tag3
        - intersection:
            - node+
            - +tag:tag4
        - exclude:
            - config.materialized:view
            - config.materialized:materialized_view
```

This selector describes a selection of nodes upstream from a single node and downstream of a union of nodes, excluding views and materialized views (custom in our dbt project).

Using this syntax, I can successfully list the nodes specified by this syntax using `dbt ls --selector test_selector --output name` and successfully run the specified models using `dbt run --selector test_selector`, but the same behaviour does not seem to work for `dbt test`.

When I try `dbt test --selector test_selector`, I receive the output

```
WARNING: Nothing to do. Try checking your model configs and model specification args
```

I would expect that similar to `dbt test`, this command would run all of the tests associated with the models specified in the `test_selector` selection, but this does not appear to be the case.

It seems that the `--selector` flag is specified for `dbt test` in the [syntax overview](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax), and the [Test Selection examples](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/test-selection-examples) portion of the docs mentions "you can use selector methods that check config properties of the resources being tested". There aren't any examples of using the `--selector` flag with tests so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Should this type of syntax be supported or am I misunderstanding the docs? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

So glad you're making use of YAML selectors!

There is a known bug when using tests + the `config.materialized:view` selector in combination: https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/2806. It's 100% limited to the "view" materialization. Given your selector definition, which excludes all `config.materialized:view`, the current behavior is to erroneously exclude *all* tests. There's nothing you're doing wrong; we're working to resolve that issue for the next version of dbt.

In the meantime, if you *can* specify that logic differently—e.g. instead of excluding all view-materialized models, excluding all models in the `staging` directory—I'd recommend giving it a go.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! I was able to specify different syntax to get around this issue.